# systemd-networkd one NIC, multiple IPs, two gateways

Tags: networking, systemd-networkd

I am using `systemd-networkd`. I have one NIC and I am using the following configuration to create multiple IPs:

```
[Match]
Name=usbceth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4

# LAN_1
[Address]
Label=usbceth0:0
Address=192.168.100.10/24

# LAN_2 (4G-LAN)
[Address]
Label=usbceth0:1
Address=192.168.50.70/24
```

If there is a DHCP, `usbceth0` gets an IP and gets a gateway assigned. The two added IPs, `usbceth0:0` and `usbceth0:1` are created normally. I need those to access different LANs. So far so good.

The network of `usbceth0:1` has also a gateway at `192.168.50.1`.

How can I add this gateway as-well in my configuration? Configure two gateways, one coming from the DHCP and one the `192.168.50.1`. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly your primary route (gateway) would be the one from the DHCP and the second would be a back up. So, you can set a static route with bigger metric, which comes in only if the primary is down.
You can check your current metrics with `route -n`.

Using the `systemd-networkd` the `.network` file should look like:

```
[Match]
Name=usbceth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4

# LAN_1
[Address]
Label=usbceth0:0
Address=192.168.100.10/24

# LAN_2 (4G-LAN)
[Address]
Label=usbceth0:1
Address=192.168.50.70/24

# "Static"-Gateway as backup
[Route]
Gateway=192.168.50.1
#Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Metric=1025 # The Gateway of the DHCP gets the default 1024
```

If it complains you can  add `Destination=` and also you can use `RouteMetric` for the DHCP route if you want to make a custom metric. Don't forget to restart the `systemd-networkd.service`.

Or you can do it with `ip route add 'Destination' via 'Gateway' metric` but this won't stay after a reboot

Comment: Correct Angel! The high level idea is this. But how do I configure this (literally)? Can this be done with `systemd-networkd` or `iptables` or some other way?

Comment: I have edited my answer with the example but as I said above it is not tested so be careful